# display two colours inside one td tag

Tags: html

Hi I want to display 2 different text colours in one area of table data IE:

```
         <tr>
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">This text is Yellow! and This test is blue </td>
         </tr>
```

Can I specify two colours inside one TD tag ? I thought this would be an easy task but I'm really struggling, Any help much appreciated !

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap them in a container element, and apply the style to the wrapping element.

```
<td bgcolor="#FFFF00">
  <span style="color:yellow">
    This text is Yellow!
  <span style="color:blue"> 
    and This test is blue 
  </span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `span` tags with the appropriate bgcolor or style attributes:

```
<tr>
<td><span style="background: yellow">yellow</span> <span style="background: blue">blue</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This will change the background colour, not the "text colour" as requested by the OP.

Comment: right, but he put a yellow bgcolor so I figured that was what he *meant*.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `span` -tags and learn CSS :)

```
<tr>
<td style="background: #ffff00;">

  <span style="color: yellow;">This text is Yellow!</span> and <span style="color: blue;">This test is blue</span>

</td>
</tr>
```